# Оптимальный способ подбора предметов в Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю небольшую игру. Пришло время создать систему предметов, которые будут выпадать в рандомных точках локации. Мне нужно, чтобы после подбора предмета он отображался на экране, чтобы игрок видел, что у него есть, например, броня, или, если игрок подбирает патроны, у него изменялось значение в соответствующей переменной. Мой способ реализации примерно такой:

1. Сделать коллекцию item ов , присвоить им ID.
2. Через скрипт игрока написать onTriggerEnter и в нем if ами прописывать. "Если ID предмета такой то - добавить, например, жизнь на экран или патроны
   Все бы ничего, но мне кажется, этот способ очень корявый, хоть и, наверное, самый простой. Есть что то оптимальнее?

Comment: Научитесь работать с наследованием, абстракциями, интерфейсами. У вас должен быть, к примеру интерфейс `public IItem { void Take(); void Use(); }`, далее вы реализуете нужные объекты `public Bullet : IItem { public void Take() { //Пуля подобрана } public void Use() { //Пуля использована } }`, имея это вы не зависите от конкретного класса, а зависите от абстракции, из за чего можете сделать уже к примеру коллекцию `var items = new List<IItem>()` в которую спокойно сможете добавить всех, кто реализует этот интерфейс, а дальше вызывать спокойно методы интерфейса.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный способ это всегда разделение на маленькие и простые ответственности.
Например:

- На игроке есть некий компонет `ItemPicker` с единственным методом `Pick(PickableItem item)`
- Подбираемый предмет сам реагирует на коллекторов как ему нужно, какие-то могут подбираться на расстоянии например патроны и валюта, к другим нужно близко подойти, например хилки. Предметы могут реагировать на `OnCollisionEnter` или считать дистанцию или смешенный вариант для разных типов. Отдавая полномочия подбора коллектору закрываются возможности реализаций и навешивая сразу две ответственности.
- Соответственно на предмете несколько компонентов. `PickDetector` отвечает за фиксацию подбирания тем или иным способом после чего происходит событие передающее `Picker` и отключение. На событие может сработать компонент анимирующий полет до пикера, после чего передать пикеру компонент `PickableItem` который может быть чем угодно.
- `ItemPicker` должен выступать в виде визитера (паттерн visitor). То-есть все предметы реализуют класс унаследованные от `PickableItem`, например `PickableAmmo` или `PickableHealth`. Метод `Pick` не совсем один, а имеет соответствующий набор перегрузок `Pick(PickableAmmo ammo)`,  `Pick(PickableHealth health)` и в зависимости от типа он сработает необходимый или базовый для неопределенного перегрузкой предмета. Под каждый тип есть события `Action<AmmoType, int> PickedAmmo`, `Action<int> PickedHealth` на которые и подписаны все заинтересованные не получая лишнего и даже не зная о существовании никаких `PickableItem`, а сразу конкретные значения, сколько хп или сколько амуниции T типа подобранно.

---

```
public abstact class PickableItem : MonoBehavour 
{ }

public enum AmmoType { Pistol, Rifle, Shotgun }

public class PickableAmmo : PickableItem
{
    public AmmoType Type;
    public int Amount;
}

public class PickableHealth : PickableItem
{
    public int Amount;
}
```

Итого 4 ответственности:

- `ItemPicker` сообщает о подобранном в отсортированном виде для разных подписчиков
- `PickDetector` отвечающий за подбор
- `PickAnimation` отвечающий за полет до пикера или просто эффект вспышки символизирующий подбирание. (опционально)
- `PickableItem` и его наследники содержащие информацию о том что находится в подобранном предмете.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! До того, как задал вопрос, даже подумать не мог, что здесь нужны интерфейсы

Comment: Я упростил ответ, они не нужны, поскольку поведение не меняется.

Comment: Под интерфейсом тут может быть пикер. Типа вдруг ты захочешь сделать питомца который бегает и собирает предметы. Он тоже будет пикер, но реализация совсем другая, никаких событий, просто складирует и передает пикеру хазяену. Или ещё что-то связанному с подбором. У типа детекта или анимаций могут быть разные реализации, но к ним никто не обращается, они работают сами по себе. А у `PickableItem` нет никаких реализаций.

Comment: Интерфейсы нужны когда одинаковое методы поведения, но разная реализация. Как например с ui `IDragHandler`, `IDropHandler`. Или с теми же магическими методами unity типа `OnCollisionEnter` которые  спрятан за рефлексией, но в не unity это были бы интерфейсы.